# Quantum Field Theory cross sections integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams, scattering-cross-section

Where can I find some examples of cross sections calculations in QFT done step-by-step? Those integrals are a little horror. For example - a simple scalar+scalar -> scalar+scalar at the tree level in a theory scalar $\phi^4$ ?

Comment: Take a look at M.Srednicki, "Quantum field theory". He is doing it in a very detailed manner.

Answer (score 10):

[Peskin and Schroeder](http://physics.weber.edu/schroeder/qftbook.html) tends to be the book used in most introductory QFT courses, so you'll definitely find all things there done in a pretty detailed way.

Warren Siegel has an online book which is also pretty good, [Fields](http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/~siegel/errata.html).